# How to search and delete a pattern from a line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to write a simple bash script that takes a text line

`some-pattern something-else`

and erases *some-pattern* and returns only something-else. I wrote a script to do the opposite with grep -o, but I don't know how I could do with this case. Any help is very much appreciated.

sample input:

```
"SNMPv2::sysLocation.0 = STRING: someLocation"
```

Desired Output:

```
"someLocation"
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: if you just want the last word on the line, the `echo "$string" | awk '{print $NF}'` will do. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Considering `"` are NOT in your sample Input_file and expected output, could you please try following with GNU `grep`.

```
grep -oP '.*STRING: \K(.*)' Input_file
someLocation
```

***For `\K` explanation:***

> \K is a PCRE extension to regex syntax discarding content prior to
> that point from being included in match output

Comment: Thanks, that did work exactly as intended. From what I understand the \K tells the command to pretend the match started right after the "STRING: ", right?

Comment: @GustavoZapata, it tells `grep` to match part and before \K don't print that matched part print whatever matched it, let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Maybe `\K` means "keep what follows"? Just a guess. Good luck to all.

Comment: great answer, first time I see \K option

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to delete the part in front of what you want to keep.

Given:

```
$ echo "$s"
"SNMPv2::sysLocation.0 = STRING: someLocation"
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -nE 's/^.*(someLocation)/\1/p'
someLocation
```

And if you want to add quotes:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -nE 's/^.*(someLocation)/"\1"/p'
"someLocation"
```

If the portion after `STRING:` is variable, not fixed, you can use `STRING:` and the capture anchor:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -nE 's/^.*STRING:[[:space:]]*(.*)/"\1"/p'
"someLocation"
```

Or, `sed` to capture and print the last word after the last space:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -nE 's/([^[:space:]]*$)/\1/p'
```

You can also use `awk` if the last word is space separated from the other fields:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Or a pipeline with `cut` and `rev` works too:

```
$ echo "$s" | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1 | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `echo ${STRING} | awk -F" " '/someLocation/ { print $NF }'`
`-F` will use space (represented by double-quotes with space between them) as separator; `/someLocation/` will search for your location; `{ print $NF }` will show the last part of your string (which, I believe, is the place where location is.